# Adding whitespaces at index 2 and 8 of mutablestring

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablestring

I am getting a string from database say,As1234512345.I want to add spaces at index 2 and 8 and then want to show this string on textfield as string "As 12345 12345".I know this can be done in shouldchangecharacterinrange.But I want to make my own method for it so that it takes the string and returns a string with spaces added at desired positions.How z it possible.Kindly help with some code snippet.Thanks in advance.

```
-(NSMutableString *)makeStringForTextfield:(UITextField*)textField withString:(NSString*)string
{
   NSMutableString *mutString=[string mutableCopy];
    NSLog(@"The value of mutablestring %@",mutString);
    if(string.length!=0)
    {

            [mutString insertString:@" " atIndex:2];
            [mutString insertString:@" " atIndex:8];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"the value of string is %@",string);
    }
    return mutString;


}
```

I have tried the above code .It works fine in case of showing data directly after fetching from database .But when I edit the text ,it doesnt add the space at 8 index position which is the real problem.

Comment: you tried anything ?.

Comment: you need methods to split a string and join them, could to with a number of ways. try some of them ) scanner/range options

Comment: Try [self convertString:@"As1234512345" positions:pos]; -(NSString *)convertString:(NSString *)string positions:(int)pos { //here do what ever you want  then return the string}

Comment: @Nazir...code added ,kindly check and help me with your suggestions !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
-(NSString*) returnStringForTextfield:(NSString*) str{
    NSString* newStr = @"";
    if(str.length>=8){
         newStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@", [str substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 2)], [str substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(2, 5)], [str substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(7,str.length-7)]];
    }
    return newStr;
}
```

use this method as-

```
NSLog(@"%@", [self returnStringForTextfield:@"As1234512345"]); //As 12345 12345
```

Comment: Its working fine for shoeing data but while editing it violates the validations and doesn't add space at 8 index position .

Comment: Is it violating validation when you start to edit the text in textfield?

Comment: yes..it is violating the valiadtion of adding space at index 2 and 8 while start editing text in textfield

Comment: Did u add any validation on textfield delegate methods?

Comment: Yes,I did...and its working fine for me too on removing the code from there...Thanks!